# Fundamental group of the union of a circle and a hyperbola

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X=\{(x,y) \in [-b,b]\times [-b,b]: \, (xy-1)(x^2+y^2-a^2)=0, 0<a<b\}$. Which is its fundamental group?

Pictorially, it is the union of the circle with a hyperbola. But I have no clue of how formalize the proof, can you help me, please?

Comment: Your intuition is wrong.

Comment: Is there any condition on your $a$?

Comment: The condition on $a$ is: $0<a<b$.

Comment: OK. What is your basepoint? Because if my intuition is right, for some cases the space is not path-connected and this means, that the choice of your basepoint determines your fundamental group in a nontrivial way.

Comment: The space is homotopy equivalent to a rose with three petals, so its path connected.

Comment: For some $a$ and $b$ you are right, but $(xy-1)(x^2+y^2-a^2)=0\Leftrightarrow y=\frac{1}{x}\vee x^2+y^2=a^2 (x\neq 0)$. But these two terms intersect only if $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=a^2\Leftrightarrow x^4-a^2x^2+1=0$ and for $a=1$ there is no real solution. So there is no intersection. Please correct me, if I am wrong. Then $b$ can be chosen, s.t. $X$ is not path-connected, because of the $y=\frac{1}{x}$ term. Sorry, but I don't see my fault.

Comment: In my example, the hyperbola and the circle meet, so I believe that $a>1$; the exercise must specify it, but it does not. I did a picture and I see that the fundamental group must be the same as that of the bouquet of three circles. But, is there a formal proof of this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve the problem by using Seifert - van Kampen. First you get by deformation retraction a space homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of three circles. You can try to give an explicit formula for two maps describing the homotopy equivalences.

I prefer the way using Seifert - van Kampen. You can divide your space into the red one $(=U)$ and the blue one $(=V)$ in the sense of Seifert - van Kampen (cf. picture below). The green intersection $U\cap V$ is homotopic equivalent to a point by deformation retraction, hence $\pi_1(U\cap V)=0$.

Obviously the blue space has $\pi_1(V)=\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$. The red space is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of two circles, hence $\pi_1(U)=\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)=\pi_1(S^1)\ast\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$. If this is not clear, use Seifert - van Kampen one more time and divide $U$ into the two spaces being homotopy equivalent to a circle in each case. Their intersection is also homotopy equivalent to a point by deformation retraction. So $\pi_1(U)=\pi_1(S^1)\ast\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$.

Because of $\pi_1(U\cap V)=0$ the normal subgroup of $\pi_1(U)\ast\pi_1(V)$ is $\ker(\Phi)=0$, where $\Phi\colon\pi_1(U)\ast\pi_1(V)\to\pi_1(X)$ and the normal subgroup is generated by $(i_{1})_\ast(\gamma)(i_{2})_\ast(\gamma)^{-1}$ ($\gamma\in\pi_1(U\cap V)$) with $i_1\colon U\cap V\to U$ and $i_1\colon U\cap V\to V$ inducing homomorphisms on the fundamental groups.

This implies $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(U)\ast\pi_1(V)=\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$.

[image: Solving the task by Seifert - van Kampen]

**Remark:** I think the proof above already suffices, because the explicit formulas will not give you any useful information beyond the proof. If you want to give a very formal proof calculating the explicit formulas, the pictures above should give you ideas.